# Integrating the quadratic Forchheimer equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology, integration, porous-media

Starting with the commonly cited Forchheimer equation:

$$\tag{1} -\frac{dp}{ds}=\frac{\mu q}{kA}+\frac{\beta \rho q^2}{A^2}$$

multiplying through by density

$$\tag{2} -\rho \frac{dp}{ds}=\frac{\mu \rho q}{kA}+\frac{\beta \rho^2 q^2}{A^2}$$

noting that $\rho q = \dot m$

Dividing (2) through by viscosity:

$$\tag{3} -\frac{\rho}{\mu} \frac{dp}{ds}=\frac{\dot m}{kA}+\frac{\beta \dot m^2}{\mu A^2}$$

Here I see I cannot completely separate the pressure dependent variables ($\rho$ and $\mu$) as I have a viscosity term on the far right-hand side of (3).

Multiplying through by the differential $ds$ and then including the integration notation:

$$\tag{4} -\int_{p_b}^p \frac{\rho}{\mu} dp=\frac{\dot m}{kA}\int_0^L ds+\frac{\beta \dot m^2}{A^2} \int_0^L \frac{1}{\mu} ds$$

**So here is my question**: $\mu$ is a function of pressure and pressure varies as a function of length (or distance).  Is it possible to solve for the integral on the far right-hand side of (4) noting the aforementioned fact?  I would also like to know what this type of problem in called in mathematics, if there is such a term for this type of problem.

Pressure as a function of length (or distance) may be written as:

$$\tag{5} p_p (p_s)=p_p(p_0)+\frac{\dot m \mu}{kA}s$$

where

$$\tag{6} p_p(p)=\frac{\mu_i z_i}{p_i}\int_{p_b}^p \frac{p}{\mu z} dp$$

where $\mu_i$, $z_i$, and $p_i$ are the normalizing viscosity, real-gas z-factor, and pressure values, respectively, which are constants, selected as the values at the inlet of the porous medium where $s=0$.

**Is it possible to invoke (5) into the $\int_0^L \frac{1}{\mu} ds$ term of (4) and perform the integration?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eqn. 3 is variable separable and can be rearranged to $$\frac{dp}{f(p)}=ds$$  The left side of the equation has to be integrated numerically.

Comment: Thanks Chester, I understand how to perform the numerical integration of the $-\frac{\rho}{\mu} dp$ term on the LHS of (3).  But how do I handle the viscosity term on the far RHS of (3)?  Is there a way I can get that viscosity term to the LHS so that I have an equation as you describe ($\frac{dp}{f(p)}=ds$)?

Comment: $\frac{1}{f(p)}=-\left[\frac{\mu \dot m}{\rho kA}+\frac{\beta \dot m^2}{\rho A^2}\right]$

Comment: so, starting from (3), multiply through by $-\frac{\mu}{\rho}$ to obtain $\frac{dp}{ds}=-\left[\frac{\mu \dot m}{\rho kA}+\frac{\beta \dot m^2}{\rho A^2}\right]$, then rearrange further?  I think I am not following, as where I'm at now, I have all the variables as a function of pressure on the RHS, which would then need to be integrated as a function of distance.  My apologies for not following, I will give more time and thought to let it sink in.

Comment: Suppose you have f(x)dx=kdy.  Could you integrate the left side? Could you integrate the right side?  The solution is $\int{f(x)dx}=ky + C$ where C is the constant of integration.

Comment: I would say yes to both questions.  I guess I might try to explain my mental sticking point as so.  Eqn (3) is $-\frac{\rho (p)}{\mu (p)} \frac{dp}{ds}=\frac{\dot m}{kA}+\frac{\beta \dot m^2}{\mu (p) A^2}$  and Eqn (4) is $-\int_{p_b}^p \underbrace{\frac{\rho (p)}{\mu (p)}}_{\text{=$f(p)$, as you have mentioned.}} dp=\frac{\dot m}{kA}\int_0^L ds+\frac{\beta \dot m^2}{A^2} \int_0^L \underbrace{\frac{1}{\mu (p)}}_{\text{=also a $f(p)$, but not on the LHS.}} ds$  I suppose I am still just not seeing what it is you are trying to show me, I'll keep trying!

Comment: $$\frac{\rho dp}{\left[\frac{\mu}{k }+\frac{\beta \dot{m}}{ A}\right]}=-\frac{\dot{m}ds}{A}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55824/discussion-between-jake-mcgregor-and-chester-miller).